# Usage of "Gonna"

Tags: word-usage

[Cambridge Online Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gonna) and [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gonna) defines the meaning of "Gonna" as

> Gonna : Informal for going to.

But,

> I'm gonna New York.

sounds odd to my ears.

I personally feel that "gonna" should be followed by a verb and its usage with a noun is wrong but I couldn't find any source to confirm it.

I want to ask if this sentence and my assumption regarding the same are correct or not? And why is it that no source mentions this rule?

Comment: **to** introduces an infinitive.

Comment: @LucianSava: **to** has about twenty possible meanings, of with an infinitive marker is but one. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. **Gonna** is not short or informal for all senses of **going to**. The only relevant sense is the "modal" sense, where **going to** indicates the future tense. **Going to** in the sense of travel or movement does not shorten to **gonna**.

As for why sources don't mention this, I think the main reason is just that documenting any language is very difficult, and documenting English grammar and vocabulary is monstrously difficult. Dictionaries and especially textbook grammars seldom get the language right. While this particular omission is pretty simple and easy to correct, there is no realistic way to document *all* of these kinds of oddities. The moral for someone learning English is: don't put too much trust in authorities writing abstractly about English; you should learn mainly by example from real usage.

Comment: ... as is **gotta**, an abbreviation of **got to**, and **wanna**, an abbreviation for **want to**.

Answer (score 1):

I have just written, [an answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/90483/29924) that shows the difference between *gonna* (the informal way to write and the natural way to say) the semi-modal verb **[be going to](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-be-going-to-i-am-going-to-work)**. It is followed by a verb in the bare infinitive form:

> **I'm going to** (gonna) write you a letter.

This is different than the present progressive of the full verb **[to go](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go)**, which is never pronounced or written as *gonna*:

> **I'm going** to New York.

The following is ungrammatical:

> *I'm gonna New York.

Comment: But _I'm gonna go to New York_ is fine :)

Comment: And sometimes people (in informal speech) contract "I'm going to" even further to "imma": "Imma go to New York".