# Is it OK to use "am/is/are going to go to..."?

Tags: phrases

Is it OK to use "... am/is/are going to go to..." or you prefer to find other words combinations?

For example, not "I'm going to go to Paris", but "I'm going to visit Paris".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply say

> I am going to Paris.

if it has already been settled.

> I am going to go to Paris.

is more uncertain than the former, and it means you are only planning on visiting the city. Either option is fine but beware of this difference, explained [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90462/going-to-vs-going-to-go-to) in detail.

I don't often find *going to go* or *going to come*, especially in conversation. It's a bit wordy so many people casually use the present continuous form instead.

For instance,

> I am going to the town tomorrow. (rather than *I am going to go to the town.*)

> Are you coming home for lunch? (rather than *Are you going to come home for lunch?*)

"Visit Paris" is also fine. Other options might be "see Paris", "travel to Paris".